# facebook events start_time format

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am fetching data from event table using fql. But I don't understand the start_time/end_time format.Seems like it is not what you get from Calender.getInstance().getTimeinMillisec(). Trying to convert it to a Java Date format. Can someone please help me with the format.

fql :
fql?q=SELECT name, venue, location, start_time FROM event WHERE eid = 209798352393506

fql json response snippet

```
{
          "eid": ....,
          "name": "Checking time format",
          "description": "",
          "start_time": 1339578000,
          "end_time": 1339664400

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - you can get this in Java like so:

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```